# How to cast an object to a nullable of type struct?

Tags: vb.net, casting

In the code base I'm working in there have a method that has the signature

```
Public Sub SetDropDownValue(Of T As Structure)(ByVal target As ListControl, ByVal value As Nullable(Of T))
```

The method I am writing is passed a parameter of type object.

How can I cast the object into something that can be passed into the `SetDropDownValue` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't be able to cast a reference type as a value type (which is what the `Structure` constraint signified).  The CLR does allow you to cast a value type as a reference type (this is known as *boxing*) but the nature of the difference between the implementation (and semantics) of these two different types makes the reverse impossible.

The only think you could do would be to create a value type that held a reference to your object as a field, but perhaps this problem may be a hint that you are going about the whole thing in the wrong way.

Comment: I was starting to think the code was getting a bit smelly. Time to rethink.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you know `T`:

```
something.SetDropDownValue(target, DirectCast(value, Nullable(Of T)))
```

See this [article](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip6.asp) for details.

If you don't know the type `T`, you're in trouble and would have to start futzing around with reflection at runtime. This is complex, dangerous, and has awful performance.